# Java error trying to add admob

Tags: android, admob

It shows red errors and I followed the instruction in Google site. Only prob in Java

> mAdView.loadAd(adRequest) 
>   Unknown class:'adRequesr'
>   Cannot resolve symbol loadAd

Answer (score 0):

maybe 
You are using the wrong import for AdRequest 
like this

`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;`

instead of

`import com.google.ads.AdRequest;`

use this import hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined or imported a class called `adRequestr`. There is no such class.

You should be importing `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest`